# PHP code executes but no output

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to learn "searching elements from mysql database using php".

For this I created a database named `randomdata`. In randomdata database there is a table named `randomtable`. In this table there are four columns: Name, Surname, Email and Gender.

I want to search people by there Gender. For this I tried following query.

```
 $query="SELECT * FROM randomtable WHERE Gender =' ".$gender . " ' ";
```

I tried both, GET and POST functions. But still I am not able to take output. I am using these.

- Windows 8
- Wampserver
- Notepad++

  I restarted server and PC, but nothing changed. Below is my complete code.

  Find Entries: 
   
      
       Male 
       Female

  ```
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
       echo $gender=$_POST['$gender'];
      $connect=mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","", "randomdata");
      if($connect)
      {
      //echo 'I am connected';
      $query="SELECT * FROM randomtable WHERE Gender =' ".$gender . " ' ";
          echo  $query;
           $results=mysqli_query( $connect,$query);
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
          {
              echo $row['Name']  . "<br/>" . $row['Surname']  . "<br/>" . $row['Email']  .   "<br/>" ;
          }
      }
      else
      {
          die(mysql_error());
      }
  }
  ?>
  ```

Comment: print your query and run it in phpmyadmin.than check is all things goes well ?

Comment: Maybe changing `$_POST['$gender']` to `$_POST['gender']`? Shooting in the dark. Maybe your `$gender` param is empty.

Comment: @user3168766 yeah you are putting `$gender` inside the `POST['$gender']` gender you getting form through POST method is not a php variable

Comment: @Rana Muhammad Waqas I solved my problem, thank you for your co-operation.

Comment: @Rana Muhammad Waqas Answer having green color sign, was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the issue is with assigning the POST variable to `$gender`

Currently you are using

```
echo $gender=$_POST['$gender'];
```

Please try changing this to

```
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
```

***UPDATE***

After testing your code it seems the `isset` is the issue. There is never a `POST['Submit']`.

To fix this you need the name attribute in the submit input ie

```
<input type="submit" Value="Search" name="Submit"/>
```

Also in the query you have spaces either side of the `$gender` variable. I now have the code working, try with this.

```
<html>
<body>
 Find Entries: <br> 
 <form action="" method="POST"> 
 <input type="radio" name="gender" Value="Male"> Male </input>
 <br> 
 <input type="radio" name="gender" Value="Female"> Female </input>
 <br> 
 <input type="submit" Value="Search"/> 
</form>
```

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['gender']))
{
     //print_r($_POST);
     $gender=$_POST['gender'];
     $connect=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","password", "randomdata");
     if($connect)
     {
        //echo 'I am connected';
        $query="SELECT * FROM randomtable WHERE Gender = '".$gender . "' ";
        //echo  $query;
        $results=mysqli_query( $connect,$query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
        {
            echo $row['Name']  . "<br/>" . $row['Surname']  . "<br/>" . $row['Email']  .   "<br/>" ;
        }
     }
     else
     {
        die(mysql_error());
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: I can send you whole code. If you want to see. It is small code consisting of 34 lines.

Comment: @user3168766 Please provide the whole code in your question and also, please provide a print of the POST data, so we can ensure everything is as expected.

Comment: @user3168766 Also please clarify how you save the gender in the table, ie M/F or Male/Female. This may be the issue.

Comment: I saved Male and Female.

Comment: <html>
<body>
Find Entries: <br> 
<form action="" method=" POST">
<input type="radio" name="gender" Value="Male"> Male </input><br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" Value="Female"> Female </input><br>
<input type="submit"  Value="Search"/>
</form>
</body >
</html>

Comment: <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $gender = $_POST['submit'];
    $connect = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "randomdata");
    if($connect)
    {
   $query = 'SELECT * FROM randomtable WHERE Gender = "' .$gender .'"';
 
        $results = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
        {
            echo $row['Name']  . "<br/>" . $row['Surname']  . "<br/>" . $row['Email']  .   "<br/>" ;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}
?>

Comment: Please make a database with name randomdata and in that table randomtable. That should have four attributes. Name, Surname, Email and Gender.

Comment: @user3168766 all working now it seems, please see the update in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_connect` should be [mysqli_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$query="SELECT * FROM randomtable WHERE Gender ='".$gender . "'";
```

Removed extra spaces in query

Comment: I copied this excerpt and replace my previous query with it. Nothing changed.

Comment: as per @The Humble Rat change echo $gender=$_POST['$gender']; to $gender=$_POST['gender'];

Comment: @tomas I tried your suggestion. I am sorry to say nothing changed. I restarted server too.

Answer (score 0):

Is there no output at **all**? Very odd indeed.

What are you posting?

Are you sure that you're including 'submit' in your test post?

If this doesn't help, perhaps there's a more severe error that's not allowing the script to run? Are you able to see the php or apache error logs?

Comment: Yes I am including submit.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit'])) you can see this.

Comment: Just checking, sometimes it's easy to miss.
If it wasn't present then it would explain why nothing else was running.

Comment: Add the comments below the question if you need clarification.

Comment: @chandrayya-g-k I tried, I was told that my rep wasn't high enough yet. I'll work harder....

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were intending to assign the "submit" index to the $gender variable instead of the "gender" index?
Try the code below:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $gender = $_POST['submit'];
    $connect = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "randomdata");
    if($connect)
    {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM randomtable WHERE Gender = "' .$gender .'"';
        $results = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
        {
            echo $row['Name']  . "<br/>" . $row['Surname']  . "<br/>" . $row['Email']  .   "<br/>" ;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I didn't received any output.